# Composer expected class(but not found) when trying to autoload PHP file

Tags: php, file, symfony, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to autoload just a PHP file without any class in it but with helper functions instead. Something like Laravel helpers so:

```php
<?php

if (!function_exists('fixture')) {
    function fixture()
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

According to the docs it's quite easy, I am doing something like that:

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

After that, I am doing `composer dumpautoload` to regenerate the whole thing. Then the strange thing happens.

If that matters I am using Symfony 5. For as long as I keep my helper file in `src` directory I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Expected to find class "App\Helpers\helpers" in file "/srv/app/src/Helpers/helpers.php" while importing services from resource "../src/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource. in /srv/app/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/FileLoader.php:206
```

When I move it outside the src directory it seems to be working fine. It looks to me like composer decides that psr-4 is more important than the file key.

What is interesting Laravel does the same thing and it apparently works just fine. Example:

```php
"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/"
        }
    },
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? I am sure it's something silly, I just can't see what it is...

Comment: I know you accepted the below answer but this particular error is coming from the Symfony DI component.  It is trying to autowire your file thinking there is a class in there.  Just modify config/services.yaml and specify exclude your helpers.php file.  Nothing to do with autoloading.

Comment: @Cerad to rescue again :) I will try that and let you know what happened. Thanks!

Comment: Aaaaand it worked. Amazing. How do you know all that stuff @_@?

Comment: Glad to help.  I have been using Symfony 2 since it was released back in 2012.  But at the risk of being snarky, 90%+ of the Symfony questions I see can be answered by just searching on the error message. "Expected to find class" is a dead give away.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but completely slipped my mind that there's exclude thingy in services. These days I work mostly with Laravel and use Symfony only for home projects. Well anyway, thanks again. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your composer settings looks fine, it's just that the Symfony autoloader with service manager (di-container) is loading first.

You are calling the function from within a namespace, the function itself is not namespaced.

Try using `\fixture();` instead of just `fixture();` to explicitly use root namespace.

I'm not sure if there is a workaround, I just assume Symfony didn't setup the di-container to handle a function instead of a class.

A good approach would be to wire the class properly and dont use it from outside the project workflow.

Considering tests, there are easy ways to configure, [`setUp()`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/fixtures.html?highlight=setUp#more-setup-than-teardown) and load from [data providers](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#data-providers).

To load something for all tests, use the `--bootstrap` flag:

```
phpunit --bootstrap test/bootstrap.php
```

Then `bootstrap.php`:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

function fixture() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That's probably it. The problem is this happens(I mean the error) even without calling the function. When I am trying to run PHP unit to execute a dummy test it fails before it even gets to the test execution. I wonder - maybe I should just move it out of the src folder and wait for Symfony fix?

Comment: @Robert Mmmmmm the best thing would be to make a class and wire it properly instead of using an outside-global function. Or just `require_once __DIR__ . /';` the helper file in your bootstrap.php

Comment: Daniel, I agree. I do have the whole thing in the service. I am writing a testing tool for Symfony allowing for easy dummy data generation and easy API testing. This service is now already accessible via custom `ApiTestCase` which is extended by every test so I can access it like `$this->fixture()`. I just wanted to try it out. I hoped to have a `fixture()` helper so it could look a bit nicer. Inside that helper, I would either instantiate this service or just maybe call a static method on it. Not sure yet. Anway I might ditch the idea if it's too much trouble. I think your answer is very good

Comment: @Robert please see my edit, doesn't any of the phpunit stock methods help you in that case?

Comment: Ah yeah I just saw that. I am already using `setUp` and `setUpBeforeClass` for quick and easy database refreshing during tests(made magic trait for that). For data generation, I am using `nelmio/alice` bundle which generates entities with dummy data which I then can save in the database if that makes sense so I skipped data providers this time. I would like to have neat and clean wrappers like that so I can add helpers and enhancements. The whole design works fine, it's just bits and pieces that I am trying to improve it it makes sense.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer though because it's a good answer.

Comment: @Robert Sounds like a good setup, I will have a look into the data generator, I could use one, too. I encourage you to just upvote a good answer but give more time to other people before accepting! Nobody is in a rush :-) Appreciate your kudos, maybe if you just _manually_ include it, you have a quick solution.

Comment: No worries. I will publish mine when I am done with it so hopefully everyone can benefit from it. Ah well your answer makes sense but maybe someone will pop up with some magic solution to my problem then I will think about changing favourite answer :). For now  I moved it away outside of src. Not sure if it will work. I will have to check that tomorrow.

Comment: Daniel, look at the comment left by Cerad under my post.

Answer (score 0):

in config/services.yaml

```
 App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/helpers.php'
```

or

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{helpers.php}'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Keep in mind that this question is nearly a year old and already holds an accepted answer